# How can I map different indexes of an array on button click React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I have been trying to find a way so that when I click a button the next movie in the array shows up on the screen. I am new to react so please forgive my code. I think my problem is in how I am fetching data from the external site. I am not sure how/when I should load in the data so that it functions most effeciently. Any help or tips would be greatly appreciated

```
function App() {
  const [items,setItems] = useState([]);

  async function getItems() {
    const response = await fetch('https://etbd.tech/nuspljr_334360/csv2json.php');
    const data = await response.json();
    setItems([...data]);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getItems();
  },[]);

  async function loadData() {
    const response = await fetch('https://etbd.tech/nuspljr_334360/sread.php?f=imdb_top_1000.csv');
    const menu = await response.json();
    setItems([...menu]);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    loadData();
  },[]);

  function Buttons() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button className="button" onClick={nextMovie}>Next Movie</button>
      </div>
    )
  }

  function RenderItem() {
    return (
      <div>
        {items.map((item) => (
          <div key={v4()} className='card'>
            <section className="description">
              <img src={item.Poster_Link} alt="Poster_Image"/>
              <section className="title">
                <p>{item.Series_Title} ({item.Released_Year})</p>
                <p>IMDB Rating: {item.IMDB_Rating}</p>
              </section>                
              <p>{item.Overview}</p>
              <p>{item.Genre} - {item.Runtime}</p>
            </section>
          </div>  
        ))}

      </div>


    )};   

  return (
    <div className="body">
      <h2>Guess that Movie</h2>
      <div className="table">
        <RenderItem />
        <div className="nav">
          <Buttons />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>  
  );   
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I've never seen JSON sent with content-type text/html and a CSV extension before, that's a first. Have you tried defining `nextMovie`? If the goal is to render one movie at a time, the button could change an index variable, and rather than mapping over the whole list of `items`, `RenderItem` could take just `items[that-index]`. It also looks like the endpoints you're hitting return the same data, and you overwrite the first, so there's no need to fetch both.

Comment: Give me a minute, im fixing it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, some things missing in your code.
First of all, you are referencing to nextMovie function and did not declare it.

After this, you should think about the logic of your component and how it should behave.

You do have a state for storing your items that you are fetching.
Now you need another state to store some kind of logic to display the current movie and when you click the next movie button, to update this state with the next one.

You can set a const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(-1);

When you first fetch your items, you can set movieIndex to 0.

And inside your component render item, you will get rid of the items.map; because you don't want to loop inside your array, you just want to show one.

We are now passing the active movie as a prop to RenderItem component and showing the active movie data.

I recommend that you learn more about javascript before trying react code.

You can see a working demo here: https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-sid-8morgf?file=/src/App.js

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'

function App() {
  const [items,setItems] = useState([]);
  const [activeIndex,setActiveIndex] = useState(-1);

  async function getItems() {
    const response = await fetch('https://etbd.tech/nuspljr_334360/csv2json.php');
    const data = await response.json();
    
    setActiveIndex(0);
    setItems([...data]);

  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getItems();
  },[]);

  function Buttons() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button className="button" onClick={nextMovie}>Next Movie - next index {activeIndex + 1}</button>
      </div>
    )
  }

  function RenderItem({item}) {
    return (
      <div>
          <div className='card'>
            <section className="description">
              <img src={item.Poster_Link} alt="Poster_Image" />
              <section className="title">
                <p>{item.Series_Title} ({item.Released_Year})</p>
                <p>IMDB Rating: {item.IMDB_Rating}</p>
              </section>                
              <p>{item.Overview}</p>
              <p>{item.Genre} - {item.Runtime}</p>
            </section>
          </div>  
      </div>
    )};   

    const nextMovie = () => setActiveIndex((prev) => prev + 1);

  return (
    <div className="body">
      <h2>Guess that Movie</h2>
      <div className="table">
      {items.length === 0 ? 'Loading...' : (<>
        <RenderItem item={items[activeIndex]} />
        <div className="nav">
          <Buttons />
        </div>
      </>)}
      </div>
    </div>  
  );   
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I removed your second fetch function because it seemed that the API wasnt working. Feel free to try to implement it yourself.